# Nested for loop in Bash using structure

Tags: bash, for-loop, command-line, structure, nested-loops

I'm running a nested for loop in bash using structure for a class. I've written the script and it works but I'm confused about why the character (which is bolded), K in this case, is necessary in the curly brackets after structure -K when I've already stated that I want K 1-5?
This is what I have-

```
for K in {1..5}
do
    for run in {1..3}
    do
        echo "K = ${K}; run = ${run}"
        structure -K **${K}** -o K_${K}_run_${run}.txt
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script, the only place the variable expansions need delimiting with `${}` is:

```
K_${K}_run_${run}.txt
```

Because:

- The valid variable constituent characters are all alphabetic characters, digits, and underscore, in Regex term: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
- So you need to delimit one variable expansion if the following character also is a valid variable constituent character

In `K_${K}_run_${run}.txt`:

- `-${K}` needs `${}` because it is followed by `_`
- `${run}` does not strictly need delimiting because it is followed by `.` which is not a valid variable constituent character

Answer (score 0):

The shell variable `$K` and the program option `-K` are two different things. You could use any variable name

```
for m in {1..5}
do
    for run in {1..3}
    do
        echo "K = ${m}; run = ${run}"
        structure -K ${m} -o K_${m}_run_${run}.txt
    done
done
```

The program does not infer a value for a missing `-K` option from an identically named shell variable.

```
for K in {1..5}
do
    for run in {1..3}
    do
        echo "K = ${K}; run = ${run}"
        # Wrong: does not assume -K ${K}
        structure -o K_${K}_run_${run}.txt
    done
done
```